# SSRS Deadlocks During Deployment

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I wonder if anyone can maybe assist please. I'm not getting much help from MS.

Scenario

1. One Reports Server (SQL 2019 with SSRS 2019) with multiple Folders as per this image [Report Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSnm.png)
2. Running Powershell Script (See below - Please note I did try ReportingServicesTools with same result)

```
        $ReportFolderName = "/ReportFolder_SSRS";
        $ReportServerIP   = "localhost";
        $ReportsUserName  = "ReportUser";
        $ReportsUserPass  = "ReportUserPassword";

        $ReportFolderName = "/$($ReportFolderName)"
        $ReportFolderName = $ReportFolderName.Replace("//","/");

        if([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ReportsUserName) -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ReportsUserPass))
        {
            $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://$($ReportServerIP)/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?WSDL" -UseDefaultCredential -ErrorAction Stop;
        }
        else
        {
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Cred = $null;
        [securestring]$Secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ReportsUserPass -AsPlainText -Force
        $Cred   = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ReportsUserName,$Secure;
        $Proxy  = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://$($ReportServerIP)/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?WSDL" -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop;
        }
    
        $DeleteAll = @(Get-RsFolderContent -ReportServerUri "http://$($ReportServerIP)/ReportServer/" -Path "$($ReportFolderName)")
    
        $CountReports  = $($DeleteAll | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }).Count;
        $CountDataSets  = $($DeleteAll | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -ne "Report" }).Count;

        Write-Host "Deleting Reports from $($ReportFolderName)"
        foreach($item in $DeleteAll)
        {
        $count++;
        Write-Host "[$($item.TypeName)] Delete $($item.Name) from $($item.Path) ... ";
        $Proxy.DeleteItem($item.Path)
        }
        Write-Host "##[section] Deleted $($CountReports) Report$(if ($CountReports -ne 1) {"s"}) and $($CountDataSets) Data Source$(if ($CountDataSets -ne 1) {"s"})";
```

3. The powershell script is compiled into an Azure Task that runs in a pipeline
4. The reports are all deployed at the same time (required)
5. The reports user has access to the reports database and is a local admin on the server

With my testing I deploy to 4 sites but then up to 3 of them will fail with the below error

> 2021-02-19T09:05:00.7668607Z ##[error]Exception calling "DeleteItem" with "1" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 65) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

We have increased the time out, re-installed the Report Server and Reports Services to ensure no corruption occurred and the agent is correct.

**The Deadlocks happen at random ID's and is not specific to that ID process**

This has happened with the above, Write-RsCatalogItem and Remove-RsCatalogItem and only occurs when multiple deployments happen to the report server.

Any help would be truly appreciated

** EDIT : Here is a extraction of a 1222 trace we ran as well which told us already what we know.

```
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e1037468 mode=S requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,owner id=process195e106f468 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594052280320 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.Catalog indexname=IX_Policy id=lock195c438e080 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594052280320
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e106f468 mode=U requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,owner id=process195e1037468 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594047299584 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.SnapshotData indexname=PK_SnapshotData id=lock195d11c6280 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594047299584
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,resource-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,EXEC CleanOrphanedPolicie
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=194 stmtstart=10482 stmtend=10532 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,NOT EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Catalog].[PolicyID] = [Policies].[PolicyID]
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,AND
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,[Policies].[PolicyFlag] = 0
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,[Policies]
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,DELETE
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.CleanOrphanedPolicies line=5 stmtstart=196 stmtend=524 sqlhandle=0x030005001f6768460dc60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,process id=process195e1037468 taskpriority=0 logused=23524 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594052280320 (2b682d85aa08) waittime=2373 ownerId=6759604 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.180 XDES=0x195e017c490 lockMode=S schedulerid=4 kpid=74580 status=suspended spid=51 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.190 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.190 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.190 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6759604 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,(R.Path = @Path OR R.Path LIKE @Prefix ESCAPE '*'
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,INNER JOIN [SnapshotData] AS SD ON R.Intermediate = SD.SnapshotDataID
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,Catalog AS R WITH (XLOCK)
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,FROM
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,TransientRefcount = TransientRefcount + case when R.Type = 8 then 1 ELSE 0 END
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,ExpirationDate = case when R.Type = 8 then DATEADD(d<c/> 14<c/> GETDATE()) ELSE ExpirationDate END<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,-- to fix VSTS 384486 keep shared dataset compiled definition for 14 days
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,SET PermanentRefcount = PermanentRefcount - 1<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,UPDATE SnapshotData
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=54 stmtstart=2638 stmtend=3638 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,process id=process195e106f468 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594047299584 (7166b320963a) waittime=2382 ownerId=6759842 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.210 XDES=0x195d5adc490 lockMode=U schedulerid=11 kpid=55224 status=suspended spid=55 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.213 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:44.213 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.213 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6759842 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,process-list
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process195e106f468
02/19/2021 12:20:46,spid23s,Unknown,deadlock-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e1037468 mode=S requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,owner id=process195e105eca8 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594052280320 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.Catalog indexname=IX_Policy id=lock195ab386a80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594052280320
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e105eca8 mode=U requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,owner id=process195e1037468 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594047299584 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.SnapshotData indexname=PK_SnapshotData id=lock195b5e2ee00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594047299584
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,resource-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,EXEC CleanOrphanedPolicie
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=194 stmtstart=10482 stmtend=10532 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,NOT EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Catalog].[PolicyID] = [Policies].[PolicyID]
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,AND
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,[Policies].[PolicyFlag] = 0
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,[Policies]
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,DELETE
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.CleanOrphanedPolicies line=5 stmtstart=196 stmtend=524 sqlhandle=0x030005001f6768460dc60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,process id=process195e1037468 taskpriority=0 logused=28364 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594052280320 (ed76754105b8) waittime=4998 ownerId=6758288 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.750 XDES=0x195e017c490 lockMode=S schedulerid=4 kpid=74580 status=suspended spid=51 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.757 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.753 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.753 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6758288 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,(R.Path = @Path OR R.Path LIKE @Prefix ESCAPE '*'
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,INNER JOIN [SnapshotData] AS SD ON R.Intermediate = SD.SnapshotDataID
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,Catalog AS R WITH (XLOCK)
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,FROM
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,TransientRefcount = TransientRefcount + case when R.Type = 8 then 1 ELSE 0 END
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,ExpirationDate = case when R.Type = 8 then DATEADD(d<c/> 14<c/> GETDATE()) ELSE ExpirationDate END<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,-- to fix VSTS 384486 keep shared dataset compiled definition for 14 days
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,SET PermanentRefcount = PermanentRefcount - 1<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,UPDATE SnapshotData
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=54 stmtstart=2638 stmtend=3638 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,process id=process195e105eca8 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594047299584 (a7101ea26f8a) waittime=4998 ownerId=6758993 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:38.020 XDES=0x195cacac490 lockMode=U schedulerid=9 kpid=76660 status=suspended spid=60 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:38.020 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:38.020 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.020 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6758993 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,process-list
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process195e105eca8
02/19/2021 12:20:44,spid40s,Unknown,deadlock-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e1037468 mode=S requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,owner id=process195e106f468 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594052280320 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.Catalog indexname=IX_Policy id=lock195aabfe180 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594052280320
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,waiter id=process195e106f468 mode=U requestType=wait
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,waiter-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,owner id=process195e1037468 mode=X
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,owner-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594047299584 dbid=5 objectname=Reports.dbo.SnapshotData indexname=PK_SnapshotData id=lock195b5e2ee00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594047299584
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,resource-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,EXEC CleanOrphanedPolicie
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=194 stmtstart=10482 stmtend=10532 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,NOT EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Catalog].[PolicyID] = [Policies].[PolicyID]
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,AND
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,[Policies].[PolicyFlag] = 0
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,[Policies]
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,DELETE
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.CleanOrphanedPolicies line=5 stmtstart=196 stmtend=524 sqlhandle=0x030005001f6768460dc60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,process id=process195e1037468 taskpriority=0 logused=28364 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594052280320 (d8f7d57a33e8) waittime=2187 ownerId=6758288 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.750 XDES=0x195e017c490 lockMode=S schedulerid=4 kpid=74580 status=suspended spid=51 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.757 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.753 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.753 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6758288 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942]
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,inputbuf
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,(R.Path = @Path OR R.Path LIKE @Prefix ESCAPE '*'
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,WHERE
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,INNER JOIN [SnapshotData] AS SD ON R.Intermediate = SD.SnapshotDataID
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,Catalog AS R WITH (XLOCK)
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,FROM
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,TransientRefcount = TransientRefcount + case when R.Type = 8 then 1 ELSE 0 END
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,ExpirationDate = case when R.Type = 8 then DATEADD(d<c/> 14<c/> GETDATE()) ELSE ExpirationDate END<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,-- to fix VSTS 384486 keep shared dataset compiled definition for 14 days
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,SET PermanentRefcount = PermanentRefcount - 1<c/>
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,UPDATE SnapshotData
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,frame procname=Reports.dbo.DeleteObject line=54 stmtstart=2638 stmtend=3638 sqlhandle=0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,executionStack
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,process id=process195e106f468 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594047299584 (a7101ea26f8a) waittime=2253 ownerId=6758401 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.783 XDES=0x195d5adc490 lockMode=U schedulerid=11 kpid=55224 status=suspended spid=55 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.783 lastbatchcompleted=2021-02-19T12:20:36.783 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.783 clientapp=Report Server hostname={Hidden} hostpid=74372 loginname=ReportUser isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=6758401 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,process-list
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process195e106f468
02/19/2021 12:20:39,spid26s,Unknown,deadlock-list
02/19/2021 12:17:27,spid58,Unknown,DBCC TRACEON 1222<c/> server process ID (SPID) 58. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Also attached is the SQL Profiler output

```
xml_report
<deadlock>
    <victim-list> <victimProcess id="process195e105f468" /> </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process
            id="process195e105f468"
            taskpriority="0"
            logused="508"
            waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594045136896 (0a1f1722cb01)"
            waittime="691"
            ownerId="14764658"
            transactionname="user_transaction"
            lasttranstarted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.593"
            XDES="0x195d5b28490"
            lockMode="U"
            schedulerid="9"
            kpid="36768"
            status="suspended"
            spid="68"
            sbid="0"
            ecid="0"
            priority="0"
            trancount="2"
            lastbatchstarted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.597"
            lastbatchcompleted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.597"
            lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.597"
            clientapp="Report Server"
            hostname="{HOSTNAME HIDDEN}"
            hostpid="66240"
            loginname="{REPORTS USER HIDDEN}"
            isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
            xactid="14764658"
            currentdb="5"
            lockTimeout="4294967295"
            clientoption1="671088672"
            clientoption2="128056"
        >
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="Reports.dbo.DeleteObject" line="92" stmtstart="5106" stmtend="5602" sqlhandle="0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    UPDATE [DataSource] SET [Flags] = [Flags] &amp; 0x7FFFFFFD, -- broken link [Link] = NULL FROM [Catalog] AS C INNER JOIN [DataSource] AS DS ON C.[ItemID] = DS.[Link] WHERE (C.Path = @Path OR C.Path LIKE @Prefix ESCAPE
                    &apos;*&apos;
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942] </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process
            id="process195e1067088"
            taskpriority="0"
            logused="32272"
            waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594052280320 (ec7e3c594ed4)"
            waittime="689"
            ownerId="14764660"
            transactionname="user_transaction"
            lasttranstarted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.593"
            XDES="0x195d9c00490"
            lockMode="S"
            schedulerid="10"
            kpid="38608"
            status="suspended"
            spid="69"
            sbid="0"
            ecid="0"
            priority="0"
            trancount="2"
            lastbatchstarted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.597"
            lastbatchcompleted="2021-02-22T08:42:24.597"
            lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.597"
            clientapp="Report Server"
            hostname="{HOSTNAME HIDDEN}"
            hostpid="66240"
            loginname="{REPORTS USER HIDDEN}"
            isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
            xactid="14764660"
            currentdb="5"
            lockTimeout="4294967295"
            clientoption1="671088672"
            clientoption2="128056"
        >
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="Reports.dbo.CleanOrphanedPolicies" line="5" stmtstart="196" stmtend="524" sqlhandle="0x030005001f6768460dc60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    DELETE [Policies] WHERE [Policies].[PolicyFlag] = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Catalog].[PolicyID] = [Policies].[PolicyID]
                </frame>
                <frame procname="Reports.dbo.DeleteObject" line="194" stmtstart="10482" stmtend="10532" sqlhandle="0x03000500960d3b7369c60401d1ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    EXEC CleanOrphanedPolicie
                </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1933249942] </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594045136896" dbid="5" objectname="Reports.dbo.DataSource" indexname="PK_DataSource" id="lock195bdb35180" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045136896">
            <owner-list> <owner id="process195e1067088" mode="X" /> </owner-list> <waiter-list> <waiter id="process195e105f468" mode="U" requestType="wait" /> </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594052280320" dbid="5" objectname="Reports.dbo.Catalog" indexname="IX_Policy" id="lock195c444a200" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594052280320">
            <owner-list> <owner id="process195e105f468" mode="X" /> </owner-list> <waiter-list> <waiter id="process195e1067088" mode="S" requestType="wait" /> </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

*** EDIT MORE : I should also add this is happening in both the SQL Webservice URL method as well as the SQL 2019 Web API method.

Comment: If you execute the script on your local machine (without azure pipeline) , will this issue still exists?

Comment: Hi Jeff,

Yes .. I ran the script directly on my local and got the same results.

Comment: So the matter has been opened with Microsoft since we cannot find a solution. If there are any progress or feedback on a resolution I will post here.